# ElasticSearch Shield Maven dependency to SBT dependency

Tags: maven, sbt

I have the following dependency in Maven:

```xml
 <repositories>
  <!-- add the elasticsearch repo -->
  <repository>
     <id>elasticsearch-releases</id>
     <url>https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases</url>
     <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
     </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
  <!-- add the shield jar as a dependency -->
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
     <artifactId>shield</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Is there a way to translate it to SBT format?

I tried:

```
resolvers += "elasticsearch-releases" at "https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.plugin" %% "shield" % "2.0.1"
```

But it failed to find this artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `%%` identifier, it appends the Scala version to the name of the artifact. Quoting [the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html#Getting+the+right+Scala+version+with):

> If you use `groupID %% artifactID % revision` rather than `groupID % artifactID % revision` (the difference is the double `%%` after the `groupID`), sbt will add your project’s Scala version to the artifact name. This is just a shortcut.

This is not the case here so you should use the single `%`:

```
resolvers += "elasticsearch-releases" at "https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.plugin" % "shield" % "2.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do it by defining the dependency explicitly.

```
libraryDependencies +=
"org.elasticsearch.plugin" %% "shield" % "2.0.1" from "https://maven.elasticsearch.org/releases/org/elasticsearch/plugin/shield/2.0.1/shield-2.0.1.jar"
```

Comment: This works but it is not really a good practice. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33974558/1743880)